# Build Mobile App in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, hybrid-mobile-app, ibm-mobile-services, devops-services

I am new to IBM Bluemix, I want to create a mobile app using bluemix. I went through many vedios and tutorials but those are based on Mobile Builder which is not part of bluemix catalog anymore. I know I can use MobileFirst service but not sure what are the exact steps. Can someone elaborate step by step to create a mobile app in bluemix.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

To start building a Mobile application on Bluemix, visit the new Mobile dashboard below:

[image: mobile dashboard home]

https://console.bluemix.net/developer/mobile/dashboard

From there, you can either choose a starter kit or services to get started.

If you select a starter kit, you can add services like Mobile Analytics, App ID (security), and Push Notifications to your project after it's created. You can also add other services like Watson or Cloudant too!

After setting it up, you can download the code, read the README, and get started coding in XCode or Android Studio.

[image: project]

Comment: Thanks Joe. But new bluemix console do not give option to build mobile app screens. I think it just have Mobile foundation server where we can host our applications. I have used Buildup.io to build one sample app but not able to deploy it on Bluemix.

Comment: The Mobile App Builder service has been deprecated from Bluemix: https://studio.buildup.io/home/news. Currently, we provide starter kits as an on-ramp for developers with using Mobile Foundation optionally for the backend.